# Applescript can't access tabs in private windows

Tags: applescript

So I wrote a small script that closes all tabs with a certain URL. It works fine in every browser I tried, except that it can't access incognito tabs. This script for example works on multiple windows, multiple tabs but doesn't work with incognito mode. Is there any way to also address incognito tabs?

```
tell application "Safari"
    close (tabs of windows whose URL contains "ecosia")
end tell
```

EDIT: It only works, if there also is an open tab with "ecosia" in a normal, non-private tab.

Comment: @user3439894 macOS Big Sur 11.4 Beta on a 13-inch MacBook Air 2019.

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry for the error, I'm just more used to Google Chrome. Still doesn't work for me, did you change any of the code?

Comment: @user3439894 OK... I have to see what I can change so it works. RE: "I had no idea what URL you were using that contained `"ecosia"`" -- Probably the search engine Ecosia.

Comment: @user3439894 Could you please test the code again? I added an edit to the original post.

Comment: @user3439894 Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around the *code* shown in your question not working when the target **URL** only exists in a *tab* of a private window in **Safari**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, albeit kludgy, will work:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    set myTabs to ¬
            (tabs of windows whose URL contains "ecosia")
    repeat with aTab in myTabs
        try
            close aTab
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```